# Python module importing itself with leading underscore but there is no corresponding .py file

Tags: python, import, pybluez

In the PyBluez source code I've noticed a couple things I haven't seen before. [This](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/bluetooth/widcomm.py) file named widcomm.py starts with the following:

```
from .btcommon import *
import socket
import struct
import threading
import os
import _widcomm
```

In the previous directory, there is no _widcomm.py or another widcomm.py. I've read that modules with a leading underscore might be "private" or accelerated, but I can't find anything about a module seemingly importing itself with an underscore.

A few lines under that you get this interesting function:

```
def dbg (*args):
    return
    sys.stdout.write (*args)
    sys.stdout.write ("\n")
```

Am I correct in thinking the code under `return` has no way of ever being executed? As far as I can tell this function serves no purpose.

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Yes, the code below `return` won't be executed. However, this has nothing to do with the `_widcomm` import.

Comment: It may be a C extension module. When writing C extensions, its common to have a .py file for stuff that doesn't need C level code that imports the stuff that does need C. As for `return`, its just a quick and dirty way of doing debug - you are meant to comment out the `return` to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [setup](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/37d78880179b2a83e7052e0c2b9393499dd3b857/setup.py) file of this Python package,

```
ext_modules.append(Extension('bluetooth._widcomm',
        include_dirs=["%s\\Inc" % WC_BASE],
        define_macros=[('_BTWLIB', None)],
        library_dirs=["%s\\Release" % WC_BASE],
        libraries=["WidcommSdklib", "ws2_32", "version", "user32",
                   "Advapi32", "Winspool", "ole32", "oleaut32"],
        sources=["widcomm\\_widcomm.cpp",
                 "widcomm\\inquirer.cpp",
                 "widcomm\\rfcommport.cpp",
                 "widcomm\\rfcommif.cpp",
                 "widcomm\\l2capconn.cpp",
                 "widcomm\\l2capif.cpp",
                 "widcomm\\sdpservice.cpp",
                 "widcomm\\util.cpp"]))
```

the `_widcomm` import refers to an extension module which is built from the [`_widcomm.cpp`](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/d7f36702bba2abc8ea41977b2eea56a17431ac6d/widcomm/_widcomm.cpp) and related C++ source files.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the obscure return statement.

You can push the blame-button on the github you linked and there you'll see following comment for the return:

> suppress debugging messages

Below that return there are said debugging-messages printing the arguments to stdout. So the return is there to not execute those messages that where there before the return. Like you guessed and @mkrieger1 commented those statements will never be executed as long the return is in place.